# My machine won't open the Ubuntu bootable USB drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, usb-installation

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad P16 Gen 1 (Intel), which currently has Windows 10 installed. I have 2 drives, one of which is dedicated to Windows. I want to install Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS to the other, but I'm having some problems. Although my laptop does recognise the USB drive, when I try to boot into it, it just cycles back into the boot selection menu. I've tried multiple USB drives, one of which I know definitely works since I used it to install Windows recently. I've also tried using both Rufus and balenaEtcher to create the installation media, but have the same problem. Can anyone please advise on what I can try next?

Cheers,
Josh

Comment: On the USB drive, be sure that the BOOT flag is set on the Ubuntu partition. I don't know how to do that in Windows.

Comment: There can be several problems; 1. Please check with `sha256sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly; 2. I checked the specs via Internet and it seems new and has nvidia graphics; 2a. Maybe you need a newer iso file (Ubuntu Desktop 23.10) to make it bootable, at least in UEFI mode with secure boot. It may help to set the drive in AHCI mode; 2b. You may need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. If it works, you may later on need a proprietary nvidia driver to release the full power of the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the problem, thanks to everyone who responded. I'd forgotten to add the keys to allow secureboot to recognise Ubuntu in the BIOS, which was causing the error. After doing that everything has worked prefectly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) It would be even better for other users with the same hardware, if you add some more details: which key or settings did you add or change?